# Faster implementation of Option.isEmpty?

Tags: performance, scala

The implementation of [isEmpty](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@isEmpty:Boolean) in [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) is straightforward - here's a sketch:

```
abstract class Option[+A]           { def isEmpty:Boolean  }
object None extends Option[Nothing] { def isEmpty=true }
final class Some extends Option[+A] { def isEmpty=false }
```

isEmpty is used extremely heavily, including inside Option itself, so its performance is significant, even though it is so trivial.

I suspect it would be faster to implement it as:

```
abstract class Option[+A] { final def isEmpty = this eq None  }
```

This implementation shouldn't require dereferencing the option or calling any methods on it, AFAIK - just a straightforward reference comparison.

I'd performance-test this, but JVM microbenchmarks are so tricky that I really have no confidence in my ability to create a meaningful result.

Are there any factors I'm overlooking?

Comment: Why would a reference comparison be faster than a method that returns a constant value?

Comment: @m-z The method must of course be called, which can't be inlined, since it's polymorphic.  So instead of a single instruction to do the reference comparison, it ends up being around 4: 1. push this 2. call isEmpty 3. set return to true/false 4. return  .  In the case that only the "empty" case is being pursued, it also avoids a needless memory reference on the option object, which is very expensive (compared to instruction times) in the rare case that it's uncached.

Comment: I agree in theory this could be faster (at least on some platforms) but unless it is possible to demonstrate the effect with some benchmark (some code using Option heavily), I am afraid it is hard to tell for sure. Another thing to consider is isEmpty is not used very frequently in functional-style Scala code, which prefers using constructs like map, foreach and getOrElse.

Comment: @Suma The implementations of map, foreach, getOrElse, and nearly everything else invoke isEmpty - see [the source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L1)

Comment: Method is bimorphic and should be optimized well by JVM, also you can replace write 'val isEmpty = true'

Comment: I'm rather sure the Scala implementation is faster than yours. Now I'm not sure if the Scala team has tested but I do know the Guava team extensively benchmarks their code and their `Option` class also has two separate classes thus avoiding the calculation and storage of the boolean for `isPresent()`. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/11.0.1/com/google/common/base/Optional.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you *might* be right.  Using the following code:

```
sealed abstract class Opshun[+A] {
  final def isEmpty = this eq Nun
  def get: A 
}
object Nun extends Opshun[Nothing] { def get = ??? }
case class Summ[+A](get: A) extends Opshun[A] {}
```

on the simplest possible test case (array of `Option` or `Opshun`), if all you do is test `isEmpty`, the pattern you suggested is 5x (!) faster, and you can verify this if you manually replace `.isEmpty` with `eq None` or a pattern match picking out `None`.

If you move to a more complex case where you test not-`isEmpty` and then get a stored value, the difference is less impressive (a third faster).

So the suggestion has merit; it's worth testing in a more official setting.

Note added in edit: this is with arrays large enough so that not everything fits in L2 cache.  Either way is equally fast when it fits in L2.

Comment: What if you make your `Summ` `final`? (Scala Some is final and this might be necessary for bi-morphism detection). One may expect `sealed` `Opshun` should be enough, but perhaps it is not?

Comment: @Suma - Doesn't matter.  The JVM is really good at detecting whether there's polymorphism or not.

Comment: @Rex If you used a big enough array that the beginning was pushed out of CPU cache before you got to isEmpty them, the 5x may be generous - I'd _guess_ that most isEmpty tests are on return values that are still fresh from the oven.  Repeated iterations over a smaller array might point one way or the other.

Comment: @EdStaub - Yes, I did, intentionally.  There is no difference if everything fits in L2.  Your point was about having to dereference, which costs next to nothing if it's already in L1 or L2 (esp. if branch prediction gets it right).

Answer (score 4):

(Based on [Eugenes Zhulenev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1177991/eugene-zhulenev)'s comment)

It seems HotSpot compiler will do this optimization automatically, as there are only two subclasses of `Option`:

[Polymorphism Performance Mysteries Explained](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue158.html):

> The Server HotSpot compiler, according to Cliff Click, deals with bi-morphism as a special case of poly-morphism: "Where the server compiler can prove only two classes reach a call site, it will insert a type-check and then statically call both targets (which may then further inline, etc)."